# If $\lim\limits_{i\to +\infty}\|x_i^1e_1+\dots+x_i^ne_n\|=0$ then $\lim\limits_{i\to +\infty}x_i^j=0,\forall j=1,\dots,n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

Trying to prove another thing, I realized that the following property would suffice to prove it:

> Let $(E,\|\|)$ be a normed $\Bbb{K}$-vector space and $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}\subset E$ be linearly independent. Consider $n$ scalar sequences $\{x^j_i\in \Bbb{K}\}_{i=1}^\infty$, $j=1,\dots,n$ such that
>   $$\lim_{i\to +\infty}\|x^1_ie_1+\dots +x^n_ie_n\|=0.$$
>   Show that $\lim\limits_{i\to+\infty}x_i^j=0,\,\, \forall j=1,\dots,n$. Here $\Bbb{K}\in \{\Bbb{R},\Bbb{C}\}$.

It seems very plausible this fact to be true, but I have no ideia how to prove it:

- Triangle inequality seems to "fail" since $\|x^1_ie_1+\dots +x^n_ie_n\|\leq |x^1_i|\|e_i\|+\dots+|x^n_i|\|e_n\|$ does not help, because it is the left side which goes to zero;
- The fact is obviously true if $n=1$, but I could not see how to use induction over $n$ in this case...

Is this "fact" really true? Any hint?

Comment: Have you tried to use projections?

Comment: @RenanManeliMezabarba For this purpose $E$ should be endowed with a inner product, shouldn't it?

Comment: Use the Hahn Banach Theorem to define bounded linear functionals $\phi_i$ such that $\phi_i(x_j) = \delta_{ij}$. You don't need  $E$ to be an inner product space.

Comment: @HansEngler Is there a simpler way of proving it? I don't want have to appeal to Hahn Banach Theorem... It is AFTER of this in the theory sequence I am following...

Comment: Work in $E'=\langle e_1,\dots,e_n\rangle$. In this case, the map $\pi_j$ defined on generators by $\pi_j(e_i)=\delta_{ij}$ isn't continuous? I may be wrong, though.

@HansEngler +1, very nice :-)

Answer (score 2):

Define for $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the function $\|(x_1, \ldots, x_n)\|_E := \|x_1e_1 + \cdots + x_n e_n\|$. It is easy to see that $\| \cdot \|_E$ actually satisfies all the properties of a norm. Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a finite-dimensional space, all norms are equivalent. Therefore there exists a constant $C > $ so that for all $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}$ the inequality
$$\max\limits_{i = 1}^n|x_i| \le C\|(x_1, \ldots, x_n)\|_E$$
holds. Now it is easy to see that the claim holds.